# HTTPWebRequest for XML containing an XSLT

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, httpwebrequest

I'm using the `HttpWebRequest` object to make a get call to a site/web service that uses XML/XSLT as its front end.  When I view the source in Firefox the XML comes up, but when I make the request in my program the transformed document is returned to me.

As the transformed document is very useless to me, how can I make the request and get the straight XML back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a problem on my end.  Basically, the host that I'm requesting from requires a real browser's UserAgent in order for the xml to come back.  Seems to me like it would be better left for ContentType or Accepts header fields, but whatever.